# What is Ruby on Rails Action Cable adapter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

looking through RoR action cable guide http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#subscription-adapter , didn't found much information about action cable adapter.

```
development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://10.10.3.153:6381
```

Could you explain what is **async** adapter and why do I need **redis** in production as adapter?

Comment: have you gotten to the configuration portion of the guide, as well as the dependencies link it provides? http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#configuration

Answer (score 5):

`async` adapter is an asynchronous version of an `inline` adapter, which stores pubs/subs in the memory of a Rails instance, therefore all data will be lost if given instance is killed. For the same reason it is not scalable.

Rails recommends Redis because it's way faster than PostgreSQL.

If you really wonder how do all subscription adapters work, you can check out [their source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter).

Comment: This does not answer what the async adapter actually is.