# Why "async" adapter for ActionCable should not be used in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

The docs for ActionCable states "The async adapter is intended for development/testing and should not be used in production."

Reference https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#adapter-configuration

What are the downsides of using "async" adapter?

Comment: For one thing it only works with a single instance/process on the backend

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Ruby on Rails Action Cable adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948416/what-is-ruby-on-rails-action-cable-adapter)